# Performance issue with state machine on android

Tags: android, performance, surfaceview, state-machine, fsm

Not sure this is an android issue, I am a c++ developer trying to write java :)

The problem in brief..
I have replaced a long and hard to maintain switch case with 
a finite state machine and while the base code is the same I get 
about 20% performance loss

Some more detailed explanation:
I've create a SurfaceView based andriod app based on the sample code from SDK
after extending my app I found myself maintaining long switch cases on my game loop

generally my app skeleton looks like this (with many cases)

```
class myView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
   public void update() {
      switch (_state) {
         case MENU: ... break;
         case LOAD: ... break;
         case RUN: ... break;
         ...
      }
   }

   public void draw(Canvas c) {
      switch (_state) {
         case MENU: ... break;
         case LOAD: ... break;
         case RUN: ... break;
         ...
      }
   }

   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      switch (_state) {
         case MENU: ... break;
         case LOAD: ... break;
         case RUN: ... break;
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

So I decided to refactor my code and implemented a simple finite state machine (FSM)

```
public class StateMachine {

    public State state;
    private myView context;

    public StateMachine(myView view) {
        context = view;
    state = new StateMainMenu();
}

    interface State {
        public void update();
        public void draw(Canvas canvas);
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event);
    }

    class StateMainMenu implements State {

    public StateMainMenu() { ... }

    @Override
    public void update() { 
            ... 
            if (windOfChange) {
               state = new StateTheNextState();
            }
        }

        @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) { ... }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            synchronized (_thread.getSurfaceHolder()) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: ... break;
                    ...
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in myView is used it like this

```
class myView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private StateMachine stateMachine = new StateMachine(this);

    public void update() {
        stateMachine.state.update();
    }

    public void draw(Canvas c) {
        stateMachine.state.draw(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        synchronized (_thread.getSurfaceHolder()) {
            return stateMachine.state.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

While, inside the states I do exactly what I did before
same amount of objects creations and the very same code
running my app I get about 20% less frame rates...

Any ideas why? or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to profile your app's execution with [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) to identify which part of it is acting as a bottleneck. Without that, it's a bit like shooting in the dark.
I would put my 2 cents on the synchronized blocks though.

Comment: Thanks, apparently the state machine wasn't my bottleneck